# How to use REF datatype in PL/SQL code or in SQL statements?

Tags: oracle, plsql, ref

In my understanding REF is an datatype which can store reference to an Object.

I have created a type person.

```
CREATE TYPE person AS OBJECT(
    names   VARCHAR2(20),
    age     NUMBER(4, 2)
);
```

I created a table of it and inserted a row.

```
create table person_table of person;
```

```
insert into person_table values ('Sam', 24);
```

Can anyone please tell how I can use `REF` to store the reference of the inserted object in some other table or PL/SQL block or use `REF` in any SQL statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to simply use `REF` in table creation which will store reference of the `PERSON` type as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
(PERSON_DETAILS REF PERSON);
```

and you can insert data into this table using `REF` keyword by pointing to the `PERSON_TABLE` which is itself table of `PERSON` type as follows:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE
SELECT REF(P) FROM PERSON_TABLE P WHERE NAMES = 'Sam';
```